# Can we use FIND_IN_SET() function for multiple column in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-administration, find-in-set

NOTE : I tried many SF solution, but none work for me. This is bit challenging for, any help will be appreciated.

Below is my SQL-Fiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6daa20/9

I have tables below:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_pay_chat` (
nId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
npayid int(11) NOT NULL,
nSender int(11) NOT NULL,
nTos varchar(255) binary DEFAULT NULL,
nCcs varchar(255) binary DEFAULT NULL,
sMailBody varchar(500) binary DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (nId)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
CHARACTER SET utf8,
COLLATE utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO tbl_pay_chat
(nId,npayid,nSender,nTos,nCcs,sMailBody)
 VALUES
(0,1,66,'3,10','98,133,10053','Hi this test maail'),
(0,1,66,'3,10','98,133,10053','test mail received');

 _____________________________________________________________

CREATE TABLE `tbl_emp` (
empid int(11) NOT NULL,
fullname varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (empid)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
CHARACTER SET utf8,
COLLATE utf8_bin;



INSERT INTO `tbl_emp` (empid,fullname)
VALUES
(3, 'Rio'),
(10, 'Christ'),
(66, 'Jack'),
(98, 'Jude'),
(133, 'Mike'),
(10053, 'James');
```

What I want :

1. JOIN above two tables to get fullname in (nTos & nCcs) columns.
2. Also, I want total COUNT() of rows.

What I tried is below query but getting multiples time FULLNAME in 'nTos and nCcs column' also please suggest to find proper number of row count.

```
 SELECT a.nId, a.npayid, e1.fullname AS nSender, sMailBody, GROUP_CONCAT(b.fullname ORDER BY b.empid) 
 AS nTos, GROUP_CONCAT(e.fullname ORDER BY e.empid) AS nCcs
 FROM    tbl_pay_chat a
    INNER JOIN tbl_emp b
        ON FIND_IN_SET(b.empid, a.nTos) > 0
    INNER JOIN tbl_emp e 
        ON FIND_IN_SET(e.empid, a.nCcs) > 0
    JOIN tbl_emp e1
        ON e1.empid = a.nSender
 GROUP   BY a.nId ORDER BY a.nId DESC;
```

I hope I made my point clear. Please help.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, although I suspect that at its heart, this is a problem of poor schema design.  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: @Strawberry, I understood but my question is very simple, and I am not allowed to share my real table data. I am very close to my task what I tried, if you can see. Also if possible please suggest possible changes, I will make the changes.

Comment: Could you add your expected result as well ?

Comment: Does your query gives the output which you need?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 what is want is fullname instead of 'ids' in 'nTos & nCcs' column, also I pasted SQL FIDDLE link , you can check.

Comment: I think that `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)`  is more safe... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=346cda45606402c7b0242f2490e34b59

Comment: See normalisation. Ccs and tos need to be in a separate table

Comment: @Akina, I am very close to my result, just need some help,I atatched SQL fiddle link, where I you can see my working. But I am getting repeated names as well as If I make count function use, it gives wrong COUNT.

Comment: @Akina, yes I am almost close, distinct helps for me. Now I just want no. of rows return. from SQL fiddle SQL query i shud get 2 but getting 6 rows in return.

Comment: Provide desired output, add it into the question text. PS. The fiddle in my comment gives 2 output rows - but you need 6 rows?

Comment: In both fiddle provided by you and @Akina do give 2 rows. What is the issue then ?

Comment: @Akina, In simple terms I want no. of rows return, I don't want 6 rows , I want 2 rows only. But how to use COUNT() function to get no. of rows.

Comment: I do not see desired output in your question. Now it is absolutely unclear WHERE do you want to see this `2 rows` and in what form.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30, yes it gives 2 rows, but how to use COUNT() to get no. of rows. If I use COUNT() function, I get 6 as values return instead if 2. My desired result for row count is 2 only.

Comment: *If I use COUNT() function, I get 6 as values return instead if 2.* ?? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d795c6d118eddc4372ca0f7dd9b8f45f

Comment: @Akina, I want total number of rows. PLease check latest SQL-Fiddle link and check last output result, where i am getting 6 as row count, instead I want 2 as rows count.

Comment: @Akina, please check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6daa20/9

and check last output, in total_rows, I am getting as 6 , but it shud return 2.

Comment: You cannot. This count is a data from another grouping level (the query performs grouping by nId whereas COUNT() needs above grouping level). If your server version is 8+ then you may use window version of COUNT(), if not then you need to create liiogical synthetic expression which may fail anytime when some special relations occures.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30, can you check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6daa20/9 and see last output result in total_rows in that I am getting 6 as row-count where I shud get as 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a horrible data model.  You should not be storing lists of ids in strings.  Why?  Here are some reasons:

- Numbers should be stored as numbers not strings.
- Relationships between tables should be declared using foreign key relationships.
- SQL has pretty poor string manipulation capabilities.
- The use of functions and type conversion in `ON` often prevents the use of indexes.

No doubt there are other good reasons.  Your data model should be using properly declared junction tables for the n-m relationships.

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other people's really, really, really, really bad design decisions.  There are some ways around this.  I think the query that you want can be expressed as:

```
 SELECT pc.nId, pc.npayid, s_e.fullname AS nSender, pc.sMailBody,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT to_e.fullname ORDER BY to_e.empid) 
 AS nTos,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cc_e.fullname ORDER BY cc_e.empid) AS nCcs
 FROM tbl_pay_chat pc INNER JOIN
      tbl_emp to_e
      ON FIND_IN_SET(to_e.empid, pc.nTos) > 0 INNER JOIN
      tbl_emp cc_e
      ON FIND_IN_SET(cc_e.empid, pc.nCcs) > 0 JOIN
      tbl_emp s_e
      ON s_e.empid = pc.nSender
 GROUP BY pc.nId
 ORDER BY pc.nId DESC;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60cd116d1bc6e54627e38a409beb0ee5) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi first of all thank you for response and suggestion. I really apprecited your valuable feedback and I do use it in my upcoming query. And Second @Akina Solved my query in comments. And I am new to this MY_SQL.

Can you please tell me how to insert comma separated number in INT datatype?

Comment: @sober . . . I think you should ask a new question.